# Unable to open (Local DynamoDB) database file after power outage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

**History**:
I was able to get read/write to my local DynamoDB environment.
I followed the AWS Documents for Downloading and Running DynamoDB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

**Issue**:
I had an accidental power outage to my computer.
Now, I get the following error after I launch the DynamoDB process

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

**Error Message**:

```
Aug 23, 2017 3:52:42 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
WARNING: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: stopped abnormally, reincarnating in 3000ms
Aug 23, 2017 3:52:45 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[2]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [14] unable to open database file
Aug 23, 2017 3:52:45 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: error running job queue
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [14] unable to open database file
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1480)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Attempts**:
This post is the closest to my error but it involves not DynamoDB but some Cloud logs, etc: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=165134

Any thoughts on how to rectify the database file?

Comment: You might try opening it with the `sqlite3` command line utility, to see if there are more useful errors.

Comment: This error can also append on M1 Mac. If you're concerned, you can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635424/dynamodb-local-setup-on-m1-apple-silicon-mac

Answer (score 27):

It could be a permission issue. try updating permissions.

```bash
sudo chown $USER docker -R
chmod 775 -R docker
```

Comment: For windows I have to run the process as local admin

Comment: What is the significance of the `dynamodb` string? What is your answer exactly doing?

Comment: `dynamodb` was the directory - I've updated it to `docker` to match amazons guide.

Answer (score 13):

It is indeed a permission issue as suggested by Zudhin https://stackoverflow.com/a/53132375/239613

In my case, I'm running Ubuntu and the quick and dirty solution I found is just changing the permissions of the local folder for the volume:

`sudo chmod 777 ./docker/dynamodb` (provided that's your local folder after following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

Comment: Has anyone been able to get this working with podman / podman-compose?

I'm getting the same error and this worked for docker, but it's not working for podman.

Answer (score 9):

Best way for me using the docker `dynamodb-local` image was to change the user to `root`, here is my partial `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  dynamodb-local:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local:latest
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ../tmp/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
```

Comment: I like this answer as it's a hassle free way how to get it working with named volumes instead of bind mounts

Answer (score 2):

I had faced a similar error with Docker on Windows and the solution was to give 'System' all the permissions for the Docker Volume which persisted the DB Data

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution was to reinstall everything.

```
rm -rf <unzipped DynamoDB Local folder>
```

Then, go back through the installation instructions.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

I'm unfamiliar with jar files. Replacing them with new jar files is like reinstalling?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on `Windows`, `start the command prompt in administrator mode` and then run your command again.

> java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In docker like environment . Same permission issue.  `sudo chmod 777 ./docker/dynamodb` .This still works in 2022

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I upgraded my MacOS to Catalina.

I installed DynamoDBLocal again via these instructions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html

and it then worked.

If you need to have your old data replicated, just copy the existing "shared-local-instance.db" file into your new installation and it will work as before.

This is caused most likely to some permission changes to file access after Catalina was put in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, give writing rights to the DynamoDB folder in your Desktop.