# How to persist data in a dockerized DynamoDB using volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

My docker compose file has two containers and looks like this

```
  version: '3'

  services:
     dynamodb:
       image: amazon/dynamodb-local
       ports: 
         - '8000:8000'
       networks:
         - testnetwork

     audit-server:
         image: audit-dynamo
         environment:
         DYNAMO_URL: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000'
         command: node app.js
         ports: 
           - '3000:3000'
         depends_on: 
           - dynamodb
         # restart: always

         networks:
           - testnetwork

  networks:
    testnetwork:
```

My goal is to mount local data to some volume. currently losing data on `docker-compose down`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

So that image uses by default in-memory dynamodb (what you can find by running docker inspect on that image)

```
"CMD [\"-jar\" \"DynamoDBLocal.jar\" \"-inMemory\"]"
```

So if you want to keep your data, you need to do something like this in your `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3'

volumes: 
  dynamodb_data:

services:
  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /home/dynamodblocal/data/
    volumes:
     - dynamodb_data:/home/dynamodblocal/data
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: Thanks Jakub. got it.

Comment: I was having issues using docker named volumes on osx. Fixed it by mounting a local path on host inside the container, e.g: - .data:/home/dynamodblocal/data

Comment: Had an issue with `.../data`, so just removed it and using `/home/dynamodblocal`. Working well with that

Comment: The problem is the folder data on the host has root permissions and I'm not able to change it to dynamodblocal using ENTRYPOINT. Any solution?

Comment: It does not work. Keep getting error message "unable to open database file"

Comment: @WeihangJian try adding `user: root` to the `dynamodb` service. It seems it needs root permission to write to the shared volume.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this docker-compose config:

```
version: '3'

volumes: 
  dynamodb_data:

services:
  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath /home/dynamodblocal
    volumes:
     - dynamodb_data:/home/dynamodblocal
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
```

Answer (score 3):

To preserve data across docker installations create volume using docker.

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none \
    --opt device=/var/opt/dynamodb_data --opt o=bind dynamodb_data
```

use `external` option:

```
version: "3"
volumes: 
  dynamodb_data:
    external: true
services:
  dynamodb-local:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    command: ["-jar", "DynamoDBLocal.jar", "-sharedDb", "-dbPath", "/home/dynamodblocal/data"]
    volumes:
      - dynamodb_data:/home/dynamodblocal/data
```

Comment: I get 

SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[shared-local-instance.db]: error running job queue
 com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [14] unable to open database file

Any idea why?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850688/unable-to-open-local-dynamodb-database-file-after-power-outage