# serverless dynamodb start --migrate error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless

If you have this kind of error being thrown while running `serverless dynamodb start --migrate`. The solution below is for you!

> CONTEXT: THIS HAS BEEN TESTED OKAY ON A MAC M1+.
>
> The same will most likely apply to a Linux running a 64bit OS.

If you are running on windows, or other OS, you can try to get the equivalent code for the solution provided below.

```
    Running "serverless" from node_modules
    Dynamodb Local Started, Visit: http://localhost:6000/shell
    Jul 18, 2022 7:09:58 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[1]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
    Jul 18, 2022 7:09:58 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: error running job queue
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:352)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
            ... 9 more
    
    Jul 18, 2022 7:09:58 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: stopped abnormally, reincarnation is not possible for in-memory database
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:01 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[2]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:01 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: error running job queue
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:352)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
            ... 9 more
    
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:01 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: stopped abnormally, reincarnation is not possible for in-memory database
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:07 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[3]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:07 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: error running job queue
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:352)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
            ... 9 more
    
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:07 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: stopped abnormally, reincarnation is not possible for in-memory database
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[4]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: error running job queue
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:352)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
            ... 9 more
    
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: stopped abnormally, reincarnation is not possible for in-memory database
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[5]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: error running job queue
    com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:293)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-osx-aarch64 in java.library.path: [/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/.dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2673)
            at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
            at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:352)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
            at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
            ... 9 more
    
    Jul 18, 2022 7:10:20 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
    SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[]: stopped abnormally, reincarnation is not possible for in-memory database
    InternalFailure: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.: DynamoDB - Error - 
    Environment: darwin, node 16.14.2, framework 3.21.0 (local) 3.21.0v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
    Docs:        docs.serverless.com
    Support:     forum.serverless.com
    Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
    
    Error:
    InternalFailure: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.
        at Request.extractError (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
        at Request.callListeners (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
        at Request.emit (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
        at Request.emit (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
        at Request.transition (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
        at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
        at /Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
        at Request.callListeners (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
        at Request.emit (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
        at Request.emit (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
        at Request.transition (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
        at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
        at /Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
        at Request.callListeners (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
        at callNextListener (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
        at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/airscholar/Dev/Projects/Nodejs/nest-serverless-dynamo/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:363:13)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are experiencing this issue and you are running a Mac (M1+ Chip) or you are running a 64bit system on linux.

You need to follow this steps to fix it:

Navigate to your `.dynamoDB` folder on your terminal and run the following command.

```
wget -O libsqlite4java-osx.dylib.arm64 'https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=io/github/ganadist/sqlite4java/libsqlite4java-osx-arm64/1.0.392/libsqlite4java-osx-arm64-1.0.392.dylib'
```

After these files have been downloaded, run the command below to generate a compatible version of `.jar` for your Mac.

```
mv DynamoDBLocal_lib/libsqlite4java-osx.dylib libsqlite4java-osx.dylib.x86_64

lipo -create -output libsqlite4java-osx.dylib.fat libsqlite4java-osx.dylib.x86_64 libsqlite4java-osx.dylib.arm64

mv libsqlite4java-osx.dylib.fat DynamoDBLocal_lib/libsqlite4java-osx.dylib
```

After running the command above, run the start command again. You should be okay.

`serverless dynamodb start --migrate`

Comment: how about for windows?

Comment: After running these commands, the error went away, however, NoSql Workbench wasn't listing the tables. After restarting everything started to work as usual. (M1 chip) Btw, this error started after upgrading my local Java version from 8 to 19.

Comment: @Eli, since windows uses DynamicLinkedLibrary(dll), download : libsqlite4java-win32-x64.dll using mentioned method, other things should follow as in the answer